# Custom UIbutton down part does not recognize touchup inside

Tags: uiview, uibutton, touch

I created a custom UIbutton and placed it onto a view which shows certain information about a package.I want the whole area to be touchable as button that was my starting point.THe problem is that only the upper half of the custom button is touchable and the down part is ignored.I set the background color to a solid one and the frame seems to be ok.

UPDATE: If i add the same custom button to superview it seems to be ok but the coordinates are not right in this case.I need to convert the coordinates of the subview to super view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling so many hours i figured out that my outer frame was smaller than it was supposed to be.